# L Value required as increment operator - C

Tags: c, lvalue

I just got a question from my Friend.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int[][3]);

int main(void){
    int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    fun(a);
    printf("\n%u",a);
    a++;//Ques 1

    printf("\n%u",a);
    printf("%d",a[2][1]-a[1][2]);

    return 0;
}

void fun(int a[][3]){
    ++a;//Ques 2
    a[1][1]++;
}
```

The line Ques 1 will throw an error of L value as 'a' is the name of a two dimensional array. But this is not happening with the case of line Ques 2.

Can any one clear this doubt?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Answer (score 7):

In Ques 1, `a` is an array and it will be converted to a non-lvalue pointer when used as operand of `++` operator and emit compile error.

In Ques 2, the argument `int a[][3]` is equivalent to `int (*a)[3]` and `++a` is an increment of pointer variable, which is acceptable.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes), pargraph 7:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the
>   array type derivation.

Answer (score 2):

When an array is passed as a function argument, it decays into a pointer to the array's first element.

**Quest 1**

`a` is an array, which is a non-modifiable lvalue. So it cannot be incremented.

**Quest 2**

The argument that is passed `int a[][3]`. This decays into a pointer to the first element, which is `int (*)[3]`, (and **not** `int *`, contrary to common belief). A pointer may be incremented, so this works.

Also, you should be using `%p` for pointers in `printf`, and not `%u`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, "L value" means something you can assign to. `a` is the name of an array. So what that line is trying to do is the same as if you were doing `a = a + 1` on the *array itself*, which doesn't make sense.

Now, what you are running into here is that C has a somewhat confusing way of treating arrays: they're really just undistinguished chunks of memory, and their name is a limited alias to the address of the beginning of the array.  When you pass an array, what C actually passes is the address of the array (or in this case, the address of a particular point in memory inside the array.)  So at Ques 2, that's actually a pointer, which *is* an L value and can be incremented.

This is called "arrays decaying to pointers" (as pointed out in a comment) and yeah, it can be confusing.